# JavaFX error loading images error on runtime

Tags: java, javafx

[Preview showed by scenebuilder is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwiec.png)

```
#minimize_Button{
    -fx-background-image: url("images/minimize.png");
}
```

the error is get when i run the program:
Apr 18, 2021 11:41:36 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager$ImageCache getCachedImage 
WARNING: Error loading image: file:/D:/Projects/IntelliJ/Java/EncryptionFX/out/production/JavaFxApplication/com/hacktivist/menuGUI/images/minimize.png 
Apr 18, 2021 11:41:36 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager$ImageCache getCachedImage 
WARNING: Error loading image: file:/D:/Projects/IntelliJ/Java/EncryptionFX/out/production/JavaFxApplication/com/hacktivist/menuGUI/images/minimize.png

**Sometimes by changing images it get fixed but in this case i have tried 3 different pics but result is the same**

Comment: Edit your question and show the file tree of your source code, including resources.  Does your program actually have a com/hacktivist/menuGUI/images/minimize.png resource?

Comment: It would be helpful to show more of your HTML and css than the snippet you have provided.

Comment: it got fixed i just had to tick the cache checkbox on the properties of button from SceneBuilder (which i was applying the background image to) and it didn't give any error then