# error in java (Javafx): com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager$ImageCache getCachedImage

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-css

I am having a problem adding an image to my button in javafx.

The program hierarchy is as in the image:

[image]

the marks are for the files working with the button

> the fxml to create the button are following

```
<Button fx:id="previos" cacheShape="false" layoutX="149.0" layoutY="416.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="114.0" />
```

> the css for the button is the following

```
#previos{
    -fx-background-image: url("IconsAndImages/left-arrow-icon.png")
}
```

I also tried to add the full path:

```
#previos{
    -fx-background-image: url("1A_Students_Attendance_System_Simple/IconsAndImages/left-arrow-icon.png")
}
```

but I got the same error

> The error I am getting is the following:

```
Jan 08, 2022 12:12:13 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager$ImageCache getCachedImage
WARNING: Error loading image: file:/C:/Users/aenas/eclipse-workspace/1A_Students_Attendance_System_Simple/bin/application/1A_Students_Attendance_System_Simple/IconsAndImages/left-arrow-icon.png
```

I tried the solution in the 3rd comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67152265/17424390), but I got the same error

Comment: Try this in your CSS file: `-fx-background-image: url("/IconsAndImages/left-arrow-icon.png")` I added a single forward slash character before `IconsAndImages`.

Comment: I recommend shifting to a [standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). I think it is also best to use maven or gradle and import their project files into your  IDE.  Then follow the [eden resource guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Comment: @Abra that solved the error, thank you, unfortunately the images did not appear on the button yet, and I do not know why

Comment: @jewelsea unfortunately, I did not use maven or gradle before, I will try to learn how to use them, after that I will try your solution, hopefully it will solve my problem

Comment: [set a graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340269/styling-a-javafx-2-button-using-fxml-only-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-button), not a background, to put an image on a button.

Comment: @jewelsea unfortunately, I added the following to my button in the FXML file `style="-fx-graphic: url('/IconsAndImages/left-arrow-icon.png')"` but nothing happened (no error but no Image)

Comment: I believe that it should work if you follow the recommendations in comments and linked tutorials.  Also see [loading resources in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other). Check the location of the image in the binary output directory for your build.

Comment: Also see [Loading classes and resources in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45173837/1155209), “non-class-file resources in a module are encapsulated by default, and hence cannot be located from outside the module unless their effective package is open”.  I don’t know if that is your issue, but, regardless, following the recommendations in that answer about resource file location is good practice IMO.

Comment: The doc for [getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Module.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-), explains the last comment more.  Again I don’t know if that is your actual issue though.

Comment: @jewelsea , Thank you for your help, I will read the resources you supplied me with, hopefully I will find the solution for my problem in one of them